# How to deliver POE and ethernet to a raspberry pi zero (W)

Tags: pi-zero, pi-zero-w

i Would like to create a POE power and ethernet delivery circuit for the pi zero, Setting aside the actual circuit of the POE and ethernet, I am first concerned on two things:

1. How do i deliver Power to the zero via the GPIO? should i feed 5v to the 5v pins? i assume that by doing this i bypass a fuse so i have to place that in my 5v output.
2. How do i deliver ethernet data to the zero via GPIO, though SPI ? something that already has native/3rd party software support because i am not experienced in the low levels of linux.

Comment: *"i assume that by doing this i bypass a fuse"* -> Yes, but you could instead use a cable end and feed it through the proper jack.  Beyond that: https://raspi.tv/2015/ethernet-on-pi-zero-how-to-put-an-ethernet-port-on-your-pi  Those adapters are easy to find online and ~$10. However, even easier are USB ethernet adapters, which should be considerably faster (like 10x).  That may complicate the POE angle though.

Comment: @goldilocks i am aware with the options you mentioned, but i do not like wires dangling around. True it is considerably easier to take that route. I am willing to take the extra steps for the sake of cleanliness, anyway am still going to create a pcb for the special purpose im using the zero, so its just a few components more. It would also be a great learning opportunity to learn POE circuit i can see that ill be using it more in the future

Comment: @goldilocks the module linked me is great stating point, i can just straight up use that exact same IC, but ill try to do a bit more digging if there is a much recent IC (since that article is 5 years ago)

Comment: You can't "bypass a fuse" because the Pi Zero **doesn't have one**

Answer (score 0):

This solution (available on Amazon) might interest you:

UGREEN Ethernet Adapter, Micro USB Ethernet Adapter with 3.3 ft Cable and Power Cord, Compatible with Fire TV Stick/4k/4k Max/Lite, Google Chromecast, Roku Express 4k, Stable and Fast, Plug and Play

Comment: how does this supply power to the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).